# Refactor code so that subroutine is unaware of callee

Tags: architecture, refactoring

I'm running into some issues regarding the (maintainability of the) code structure of my application.

I have refactored the code so generic subroutines are in place that handle common tasks in order to optimize reusabilty.
Within these subroutines sometimes additional/other actions have to be executed depending on the arguments passed to the routine by the callee.

However, I always assumed that a basic concept of software design is that a routine should not be 'aware' of the callee; a routine should not know by which routine it is called. It is getting clear to me that I need to implement this to a higher degree in my app.

How do I integrate these two seemingly opposing concepts so that my code gets more transparant?

Consider next example:

```
public void processA(){

    //specific code

    genericStuff(true);

    //specific code

}

public void processB(){

    //specific code

    genericStuff(false);

    //specific code

}

public void genericStuff (boolean doExtra){

    initializeStuff();
    doStuff();

    if(doExtra){
        doExtraStuff();
    }

    doEvenMoreStuff();
    finalizeStuff();    
}
```

If i were to decompose the functionality of the generic routine this would be the result:

```
public void processA(){

    //specific code

    initializeStuff();
    doStuff();
    doExtraStuff();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    finalizeStuff();

    //specific code

}

public void processB(){

    //specific code

    initializeStuff();
    doStuff();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    finalizeStuff();

    //specific code

}
```

You end up with repeating code. Surely that is not the aim of refactoring which focuses on centralizing functionality thereby minimizing the code base? What if routine `doEvenMoreStuff()` is no longer need? I'd have to check all the calling routines in that situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because working code seeking a refactor belongs on Code Review, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I integrate these two seemingly opposing concepts so that my
>   code gets more transparant?

Pseudo-schizophrenia. :-) It helps to detach yourself from caller and callee, think of it like two very different shoes to fill.

> Within these subroutines sometimes additional/other actions have to be
>   executed depending on who calls the generic routine.

That could be the problem here. Design reflects your mentality. If you are thinking about a function as having to have different branches of code based on who/what calls it, then it'll be very difficult to get into the mindset that allows you to design the function independent of the caller. You might be letting too much of the way the code works completely shape, rather than slightly influence, your design.

You generally want to kind of step back and look at this from a more high-level perspective. *"What should this function do? What are its parameters?"* Forget about the caller, and especially when applying a generic/reusable mindset, since code that worries about exactly where it's going to be called and by whom has little reuse.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you don't want too many disparate branches of functionality to be provided by a single function. There's a balancing act there, but imagine a function that can heal a monster, cure its diseases, damage it, or resurrect it from the dead all in one go. That really wants to be 4 separate functions, so you often want to just make it 4 separate functions. One of the reasons you might be thinking too much about various scenarios in which a function can be called is if your functions are doing too much and have too many responsibilities. In that case, refactoring often boils down to decomposing this into smaller functions that have more singular responsibilities.

**Edit in Response to Further Details**

```
public void genericStuff(boolean doExtra){
    initializeStuff();
    doStuff();
    if(doExtra){
        doExtraStuff();
    }
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    finalizeStuff();    
}
```

Given a routine like this, eliminating this `doExtra` parameter would end up with some redundant logic (`initializeStuff`, `doEvenMoreStuff`, and `finalizeStuff`).

However, decomposing it wouldn't result in adding that logic to `processA` and `processB` -- that wouldn't be decomposition so much as just eliminating the function and spilling its implementation details into the callers. If you end up splitting this function into two for higher cohesion, e.g., the result would be `genericA` and `genericB`:

```
public void genericA(){
    initializeStuff();
    doStuff();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    finalizeStuff();
}

public void genericB(){
    initializeStuff();
    doStuff();
    doExtraStuff();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    finalizeStuff();
}
```

**Temporal Coupling**

It's worth noting that there's *temporal coupling* going on with the need to `initialize` and `finalize`. An interface that depends on the order in which its functions are called (and especially one that doesn't have some mechanism in place to check for errors) can be a source of human error and maintenance problems, so you typically don't want to expose the need to deal with this initialize and finalize work to `processA` and `processB`. One strategy when dealing with temporal coupling in an auxiliary interface while designing an interface is like this:

```
void some_function(function whatToDo){
    initializeStuff();
    whatToDo();
    finalizeStuff();    
}
```

This hides away the need to init and finalize, to begin and end, to start and commit, to start up and shut down, etc. from the outside world, keeping the need to deal with error-prone logic to a small number of centralized functions. Clients can pass what they want to do in between `initializeStuff` and `finalizeStuff` in the form of a function containing what they want to be executed. Languages that support closures can make this really easy to do.

**Nondescript**

However, `doExtra` isn't like a branching control variable. It's not a parameter that causes a totally different thing to happen, merely an extra thing to happen. As long as this optional extra behavior is logically tied with what the function is doing, it's not necessarily a source of confusion or maintenance problems.

Here one of the difficulties is that we're describing functions in a nondescript kind of sense. To really determine whether a function is doing something logical and functionally-related depends a lot on human factors and even the way you name your functions, not merely metrics like coupling and the amount of external memory modified, e.g. So to take this discussion further would have to use some descriptive examples where we can try to better determine the logical units of work, and whether they make much sense or are merely a source of confusion.

**Side Effects**

Nevertheless, some factors to concern yourself with would be things like side effects. A function should typically make its side effects (what it modifies) clear while few in number (ideally one very high-level kind of side effect or none at all).

As an example, a function that makes a room hot while dimming the lights has two very disparate side effects. That could become a source of confusion where a person wanting to make the room dark might end up making it hot by accident, or vice versa. Even if both of these disparate side effects are well-understood, that limits the reuse of the function to a very narrow context where someone happens to want both of these side effects simultaneously. It is typically far better to design functions that have one clear side effect (one function to adjust room temperature, another to adjust its lighting).

**Pure Functions**

The most ideal kind of function that is typically easily understood and leads to the smallest number of human errors is the pure function: a function which has zero side effects. It doesn't change anything, doesn't output something to external memory/devices, it modifies only local states created for that function. An example of such a function is an `abs` function return absolute value. You give it a possibly-negative value, the function returns a positive value. It doesn't change anything, it doesn't print anything (that would be a side effect), etc. It merely computes something and returns the result.

Nevertheless, even the simplest program requires a side effect somewhere (ex: at the bottom of the call stack where some final result is printed). To program anything more complex typically requires some kind of persistent memory and changes made to it. Despite this, it's an ideal to keep in mind: pure functions are very easy to use and test and avoid misuse.

**Coupling**

Another kind of general reason to decompose functions is to reduce coupling and increase cohesion (high cohesion and low coupling often tend to go hand-in-hand). For example, take a function that does a bunch of complex math and draws a graphical representation of its result. In that case, there is one clear side effect: the drawing of the results to the screen. Nevertheless, what if you want to update to a whole new graphical library? In that case, you end up losing the valuable mathematical work you did in the old function that was written against the old library. You now either have to revisit the old function and rewrite it to work for your new graphics library or write a whole new one.

Because of this, it can be helpful to split away and decouple that mathematical part away from the graphics part and split them into two separate functions. Calling the mathematical one might invoke a pure function that outputs some result (it could be more complex than a number, like a collection of points computed for a bezier curve). Then you can feed those results to the graphical function to draw.

By splitting the two up, only the second drawing routine is invalidated if you change your graphics library. The mathematical part stays good.

**Interfaces**

A lot of the discipline of software engineering is revolved around making changes to existing codebases quicker, less error-prone, more localized in nature. We can see from the above example that combining complex math and graphical output together can result in changes that are far more intrusive, requires sifting through larger bodies of code, and potentially making more mistakes if we update the graphics library.

Often one of the keys to large-scale design is to understand that *interfaces* matter a lot more than *implementations*. Take a function to draw a button to the screen. If you design it carefully, it'll express a high-level intent without concerning itself with exposing many underlying details about how a button is actually drawn to the screen. Maybe something like this (simple example):

```
// Draws a button to the indicated screen at (x,y) with the 
// specified size.
void draw_button(ScreenInterface screen, int x, int y, int w, int h);
```

This exposes very few details about its inner workings, only a dependency to some abstract screen interface. Let's say the initial implementation takes 50 lines of code. However, it could be *used* by 10,000 lines of code written by various people in a large codebase. Changing the actual interface to draw a button above would be very costly, requiring us to revisit 10,000 lines of code scattered throughout the entire codebase.

If we want to just change the implementation of this function, we only have to potentially redo 50 lines of code, and don't have to touch any of the code calling the function. That's why, in a large-scale codebase, designing an interface for a function properly is often far more important than providing the most ideal implementation for it. We can easily swap and replace implementations with better ones in a very localized way. We can't just keep changing our minds about the interfaces, as that would require cascading changes throughout the entire codebase.

**Conclusion**

So these are some factors to think about when designing functions. And it is a balancing act -- there are trade-offs in every kind of design decision. Occasionally you might want to expose temporal coupling in a design, even if that's error-prone. There might be good reasons compelling you otherwise even though temporal coupling is generally considered bad. Sometimes you might want to increase the number of lines of code implementing functions in order to achieve a more decoupled design with more independent entities that are decoupled from each other. In some rare case you might really need a function that has two logical side effects (though still closely related).

It's all case-by-case. Designing software wouldn't be so difficult if a clear "best" decision was present at all times. It's typically about balancing trade-offs.

But most of all, I'd suggest not to look at designing functions so much as about reducing line counts. Think of it as designating very logical units of work. The line count will typically go down through reusing existing units of work, but don't create functions with such a major focus on just reducing the number of lines of code.

Comment: Thank you Ike for your answer. I've extended to question with an example. Is this the 'balancing act' you speak of?

Comment: I've extended the answer based on your edits. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Thank you again for your elaborate and enlightening reply. No easy rule-of-thumbs. I will look at my code with new eyes!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a procedure X that has to perform a client-specific action A,
you can simply pass A to X as a *procedure parameter*.   X can then invoke the parameter A "at the right place" in its  processing.

Most languages these days allow one to pass a procedure as a parameter somehow.  (Java famously was not, but got around it by putting the procedure as a method into an object, and then passing the object; I think Java8 has real "lambdas" now).

Sometimes those procedures have to have an explicit name; often, such procedures can be nameless (e.g., lambdas).

Following you style, I'd rewrite you example:

```
 public void processA_helper() {
    doExtraStuff();
 }

 public void processA(){
   //specific code
   genericStuff(processA_helper);
   //specific code
 }

 public void processB_helper() {
    // nothing to do
 }

 public void processB(){
    //specific code
    genericStuff(processB_helper);
    //specific code
 }

 public void genericStuff (procedure caller_specific_action){
    initializeStuff();
    doStuff();
    caller_specific_action();
    doEvenMoreStuff();
    finalizeStuff();    
}
```

If your language has lexical scoping, the caller_specific_cation can (nicely) refer to variables in the calling context.   (You don't want your caller-specific action to manipulate variables internal to the generic; that would be a terrible violation of modularity).